# Remove decimal number from the function eval()

Tags: python, list, eval

I have a problem with my code.  I use "eval()" and the problem is that I have a lot of resultat like it :

```
7*1*6*10-9+3 => 414
7*1*6*10-9-3 => 408
7*1*6*10-9*3 => 393
7*1*6*10-9/3 => 417.0
7*1*6*10/9*3 => 140.0
7*1*6/10*9*3 => 113.4
7*1/6+10*9*3 => 271.1666666666667
7*1/6*10*9+3 => 108.00000000000001
7*1/6*10*9-3 => 102.00000000000001
7*1/6*10*9*3 => 315.00000000000006
7/1+6+10*9+3 => 106.0
7/1+6+10*9*3 => 283.0
7/1+6*10*9+3 => 550.0
7/1+6*10*9-3 => 544.0
```

My code to get the result is

```
eval(operation), like eval('7*1*6*10-9+3') etc
```

I would like not display the decimal number like 33,33 or 102,000001. But I would like display 106.0 without the ",0"   just like it :  "106"

Thanks for reading me !!

Comment: I cited one of many possible references for output formatting.  I suggest you look up the Python documentation so you solve all of your upcoming formatting questions.

Comment: It's not same thing

Comment: No, but it leads you directly to the formatting issues you need to choose.  Your question isn't quite clear enough, specifying only one output example.  Learn the `d`, `g`m and `f` formats to cover any of the possible interpretations.